# System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Is it possible to get all the points of the objects we have drawn using Graphics object.
For example I have drawn an ellipse using
 Collapse

```
Graphics g = this.GetGraphics();
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 300, 300, 100, 200);
```

Than
How I can get all the points or pixels drawn by that function
Or is it possible to get all the points or pixels drawn on form.

Thanks……….

Comment: Could you add some more context to your question which illustrates what you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To answer the second part of your question, on how to find pixels affected:*

I would **highly** recommend a mathmatical solution, as listed above.  However, for a more `brute-force` option, you could simply to create a image, draw to it, and then loop through each pixel to find those pixels affected.  This *will* work, but will be **very slow** as compared to a genuine mathmatical solution.  It will grow slower as the size of the image increases.

This will *not* work if you antialiasis your drawn circle, whereas their may be shading and transparency.  It will however work for what you have listed above.

e.g.

```
...

List<Point> points = CreateImage(Color.Red,600,600);

...

    private List<Point> CreateImage(Color drawColor, int width, int height)
    {
        // Create new temporary bitmap.
        Bitmap background = new Bitmap(width, height);

        // Create new graphics object.
        Graphics buffer = Graphics.FromImage(background);

        // Draw your circle.
        buffer.DrawEllipse(new Pen(drawColor,1), 300, 300, 100, 200);

        // Set the background of the form to your newly created bitmap, if desired.
        this.BackgroundImage = background;

        // Create a list to hold points, and loop through each pixel.
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        for (int y = 0; y < background.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < background.Width; x++)
            {
                // Does the pixel color match the drawing color?
                // If so, add it to our list of points.
                Color c = background.GetPixel(x,y);
                if (c.A == drawColor.A &&
                    c.R == drawColor.R &&
                    c.G == drawColor.G &&
                    c.B == drawColor.B)
                {
                    points.Add(new Point(x,y));
                }
            }
        }
        return points;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the mathematical solution will work in a machine (graphics card) independent way.  The mathematical solution would not be able to account for how the rendering engine attempts to pixellate (is that a word) the curve, which can be resolution and driver dependent.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function - as far as I know. But calculating all those points would not be difficult as you just need to have a function to calculate according to the function of the shape.

[Ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) has this function, you can just put X values from start to end and calculate Y from it which should give you all points:

[image]